# microsoft excel -vba error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Can any one please tell me why if function is showing type mismatch for `If Not j Is Nothing Then`

I am trying to make  a macro to search a list of variables (having a particular value to the cell next to that variable) in one sheet (here given as reportsheet) with another sheet having those variables and its new value and to copy them to reportsheet to compare them.

If I declare `j` as `range` then I am unable to search since I have to remove `.select` and add set `j` to the below line

`j = Range("h1:q3000").find(What:=variablename).Select`

```
Option Explicit

Sub search_and_find()

Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
Dim variablename As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As String
Dim k As Integer
Dim finalrsheet As Integer

Set datasheet = Sheet1
Set reportsheet = Sheet2

reportsheet.Select
Range("a1").Select
With ActiveSheet
finalrsheet = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
 For i = 2 To finalrsheet
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheet3.Activate
    Range("a1").PasteSpecial
    variablename = Range("a1")
    datasheet.Activate
    j = Range("h1:q3000").find(What:=variablename).Select
        If Not j Is Nothing Then
        Selection.Offset(0, 5).Copy
        reportsheet.Activate
        Cells(i, 4).PasteSpecial
        Else
        reportsheet.Activate
        Cells(i, 5).Value = "Need to find Manually"
        End If
 Next i
    reportsheet.Activate
    For k = 2 To finalrsheet
        If Cells(k, 5).Value = "Need to find Manually" Then
        Cells(k, 5).Value = "Need to find Manually"
        ElseIf Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 4).Value Then
        Cells(k, 5).Value = "No change"
        Else
        Cells(k, 5).Value = "Changed"
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't add a `.Select` to a variable assignment. That just doesn't make sense. Declare j as a variant, then remove the `.Select`. Now it can be anything it is assigned.

Comment: Side note: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to be useful